# PHP - file_get_contents('php://input') é o único jeito de ler requisição contentType=application/json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, content-type

Eu tenho o seguinte método Jquery Ajax

```
        function postRefreshJson(_action, jsonModel)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: _action,
                method: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonModel),
                success: function (r) {
                    console.log("success: " + r);
                    alert(r);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("Erro: " + e);
                    alert("Erro: " + e.responseJSON.errorMessage);
                    $("body").css("cursor", "default");
                }
            });
        }
```

Que eu chamo mais ou menos assim:

```
        var jsonModel = new Object();
        jsonModel.id = id;
        jsonModel.text = text;

        postRefreshJson("algumaUrl.php", jsonModel);
```

O único jeito que encontrei de receber o conteúdo da requisição acima foi usando

```
 $jsonObj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Não existe um jeito diferente de acessar o conteúdo enviado? Sei lá Usando $_POST?

Eu estou usando application/json, mas na verdade não esta muito claro para mim, quais são as vantagens de utiliza-lo

A sim, eu também gostaria de saber quais as implicações de utilizar:

```
  json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: cara.. da uma olhada nessa ótima resposta no SO global: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792/6344251